# PDF preview using embed tag with Django

Tags: django, pdf

Well, I'm new on this.
I want to know if I can display a PDF file in my Django template using embed tag like:

```
<embed src="/file/to/pdf/some_pdf.pdf" />
```

I tried:

```
<embed src="{{form.file_path.value}}" width="500" height="525" />
```

Where {{form.file_path.value}} is my pdf file directory or name saved in the database.

This is the **forms.py** file:

```
fields = [
            'title',
            'publication_date',
            'file_path',
            'size',
            'authors',
            'editorial',
        ]
        labels = {
            'title': 'Title',
            'publication_date': 'Publication Date',
            'file_path': 'File preview',
            'size': 'Size',
            'authors': 'Authors',
            'editorial': 'Editorial',
        }

        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'publication_date':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'file_path':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'size':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'authors': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'editorial': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

And this is the **views.py** file:

```
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'book/book_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'book'
    queryset = Book.objects.prefetch_related('authors')
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookList,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        book_list =Book.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(book_list,self.paginate_by)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            book_list = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            file_book = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            book_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['book_list'] = book_list
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

**I solved it!** 
I did something like:

```
<embed src="{%static '/previews/'%}{{form.file_path.value}}#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="500" height="525" />
```